# Background required for Computational Geometry

Tags: soft-question, computational-geometry

I am hoping to enroll in Computational Geometry course this spring. [This](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642096816) was the textbook used for the course in the past.

I am trying to figure out if I have required **math** background for this course.
 I finished Linear and Abstract algebra in fall and I would be taking Calc I in spring as far as my math background goes.

Comment: Now where's [Joseph O'Rourke](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/237/joseph-orourke) when we need him?